# How do I deserialize output from mongo-go-driver as bson array into a []interface{} when primitive.A is bson []interface

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I have a map[string]interface{} that generated from a mongo query that is using the new mongo-go-driver

I want to process certain values in the map and replace the £ characters in the values belonging to the aggregate key

Here is the map:

```
result2 = map[aggregate:[map[£match:map[Source:Cities]] map[£sort:map[Order:1]]] collection:aggregate_stats db:stats]
```

Looping through the map:

```
    for key, value := range result2 {
        fmt.Println("key from result2:", key, " || ", "value from result 2:", value)
        if key == "aggregate" {
            fmt.Println("FOUND AGGREGATE || ", "value:", value, " || type: ", reflect.TypeOf(value))
        }
        if valueMSI, ok := value.([]interface{}); ok {
            fmt.Println("Working", valueMSI)
            fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(valueMSI))
        }
    }
```

Now, in the if statement checking for the aggregate key, the output of the first print statement gives the type as:

```
primitive.A
```

But it appears to be an []interface{} of maps when printed? [see result2]

Bearing that in mind, **why isn't the second if statement evaluated?**

Does this mean that primitive.A != array of interfaces?

In the documentation https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive type A is defined as "An A represents a BSON array. This type can be used to represent a BSON array in a concise and readable manner. It should generally be used when serializing to BSON. For deserializing, the RawArray or Array types should be used."

How can I do this? I want to access the values for the aggregate key?

Comment: Why not use `value.(primitive.A)`?

Comment: @mkopriva we are using functions that convert the £ to $ that takes in interfaces (since it's a package that has scope outside of this file). So ideally, we'd like everything to work with it

Comment: ... *"Does this mean that primitive.A != array of interfaces?"* `primitive.A` is a *slice of interfaces* however it is not the *same* **type** as `[]interface{}` that's why your **type assertion** fails. They do share the same memory layout so converting one to the other is easy as `T(v)`.

Comment: I get what you mean, but i'm asking how to convert primitive.A to a []interface{} since they're similar in nature

Comment: [example](https://play.golang.org/p/501O3nz7Aph)

Comment: Hey that worked great, thanks for the explanation - if you wanted to add it as an answer i'd mark it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a value of type `primitive.A` to `[]interface{}` by using the *[conversion expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)*, the form of which is `T(x)`.

So in your case you can do this:

```
for key, value := range result2 {
    fmt.Println("key from result2:", key, " || ", "value from result 2:", value)
    if key == "aggregate" {
        fmt.Println("FOUND AGGREGATE || ", "value:", value, " || type: ", reflect.TypeOf(value))
    }
    if pa, ok := value.(primitive.A); ok {
        valueMSI := []interface{}(pa)
        fmt.Println("Working", valueMSI)
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(valueMSI))
    }
}
```

---

As explained in the documentation you can convert a non-constant value x to type T in any of these cases (I've added emphasis for the case relevant to your question):

> - x is assignable to T.
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), **x's type and T have identical
>     underlying types.**
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T are pointer types
>     that are not defined types, and their pointer base types have
>     identical underlying types.
> - x's type and T are both integer or floating point types.
> - x's type and T are both complex types.
> - x is an integer or a slice of bytes or runes and T is a string type.
> - x is a string and T is a slice of bytes or runes.

---

A bit on [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) (emphasis added):

> Each type T has an *underlying type*: If T is one of the predeclared
>   boolean, numeric, or string types, or a **type literal**, the
>   corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, **T's underlying
>   type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type
>   declaration.**

Since `primitive.A` is defined using the *type literal* `[]interface{}` it has the same *underlying type* as `[]interface{}`.

- The underlying type of `[]interface{}` is `[]interface{}`.
- The underlying type of `primitive.A` is `[]interface{}`.